# Weird interaction between gvm, .profile and lightdm Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: bash, .profile, gvm, ubuntu-14.10

Good morning everyone,

I have a strange interaction problem between gvm, my .profile and lightdm on Ubuntu 14.10.

The line that gvm puts at the end of .profile looks like this:

```
[[ -s "/home/clh/.gvm/bin/gvm-init.sh" ]] && source "/home/clh/.gvm/bin/gvm-init.sh"
```

It seems that lightdm, which I guess processes .profile upon login, doesn't like that line, for a popup during the login process states

```
/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: 25 /home/clh/.profile: [[ not found
```

To me this looks like lightdm is using sh and not bash to handle the test.  It also seems like this must be a recent change because I have been using the gvm - lightdm combo for several months now and I just started noticing this in the last week or so.

Anyway, I have "fixed" this by changing my .profile so that the last line, put in by gvm, now looks like:

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    [[ -s "/home/clh/.gvm/bin/gvm-init.sh" ]] && source "/home/clh/.gvm/bin/gvm-init.sh"
fi
```

I say "fixed" because the popup message has gone away and gvm seems to run.

But if anyone else has any better ideas, I'm all ears...

Comment: Changing `[[` to `[` in the original line would likely also have been enough. There's nothing about that usage of `[[` that requires the bash enhanced test that `[[` is.

Comment: sh doesn't like "source" either.  and when I replaced the line with "test -s" and turned "source" into "." lightdm did not like whatever was in gvm-init.sh because it would start to login, flash, then give me the login screen again.

Comment: That should probably properly be guarded by a check for interactive mode more than anything else.

Comment: Just digging around in the various bits of wisdom on lightdm and other dm's and .profile vs. .xprofile vs. .xsessionrc... this is an incredibly messed-up topic area.  No one seems to be able to agree on anything.  Nevertheless, Etan, thanks for the comment.  I guess you are correct when you say gvm-init.sh is really only applicable to interactive logins.  Perhaps this isn't "thought of" since there seem to be less oportunities for non-interactive login these days (few running rsh any more etc).

Comment: So with some more looking around, I see that I was correct in surmising that lightdm uses sh to invoke .profile, see the code in /usr/sbin/lightdm-session.  I will file a bug report with the gvm folks...